# 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: time, nginx, gateway, out

I am getting this "nginx 504 gateway timeout" when accessing my website, even when low traffic, server is 1000mbit, 36GB RAM and 2(Intel Xeon 2556). All traffic going to my site comes through a proxy server (but this error occurs even when connecting directly to the server ip)

What could be the reason, and a possible solution to this?

Comment: isn't there some sort of server log you can check? something like: /var/log/nginx-error.log? I doubt anyone can solve this problem with just an HTTP error code. You may need to log into the server to get more information

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the load time of your site (eg. php script) is bigger than the proxy timeout value?

Nginx simple say: "ok I've tried but not respond in time", maybe your webserver behind nginx have a service port, try to load the website with point to this port and you can understand what is the issue.

Comment: Sorry, in my post i ment, website is down when low traffic - but up when VERY low traffic, sometimes it goes down when 15 people are on my site - sometimes when 40.

Comment: Try to test with hosttracker and check if you are flooded by someone.

Comment: The proxy I am using should work as ddos protection, 1+ mmps and 10gbps. http://puu.sh/30l1L.png - connecting to the server through other ports seems to work just fine, Remote Desktop aswell.

Comment: Ah, it was the ddos protection that is useless for HTML filtering.